# How do I push multiple arrays in Javascript and return them from a function?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

In the snippet below I tried to add another function that compares every line against the lines that I know will come out so that if it finds it, it returns a query that I need to run onto the screen

```
error: there were errors found during runtime 12.0
warning: incorrect info 1.0
warning: file at 'C://localhost/myfiles' not found 0.0
warning: file at 'C://localhost/css' not found 0.0
warning: file at 'C://localhost/js' not found 0.0
warning: file at 'C://localhost/assets' not found 5615612.0
```

This is what I tried to do but I don't know how to ignore the numbers so that the lines could actually compare. *All of this happens after the first section is ran where I get the numbers that are grater than 0.0.*

Meaning these lines get compared:

**error: there were errors found during runtime 12.0

warning: incorrect info 1.0

warning: file at 'C://localhost/assets' not found 5615612.0**

and these are my conditions:

```
if ("error: there were errors found during runtime 12.0" == line){
    //run this query for database runtimeDB
}
if("warning: incorrect info 1.0" == line){
    //this query
    //+1 for incorrectInfoDB
}
if("warning: file at 'C://localhost/myfiles' not found 0.0" == line){
    //this query
    //+1 for incorrectInfoDB
}
if("warning: file at 'C://localhost/css' not found 0.0" == line){
    //this query
    //+1 for outerfilesDB
}
if("warning: file at 'C://localhost/css' not found 0.0" == line){
    //this query
    //+1 for outerfilesDB
}
if("warning: file at 'C://localhost/js' not found 0.0" == line){
    //this query
    //+1 for outerfilesDB
}
if("warning: file at 'C://localhost/assets' not found 0.0" == line){
    //this query
    //+1 for outerfilesDB
}
```

What I was thinking was to use the getLines() funtion and from there go to this function which returns the string without the last numbers so that the comparison can be made.

```
function trim_numbers($string) {
    $numbers = strrchr($string, ' ');
    return str_replace($numbers, '', $string);
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to push the arrays so that they are all within the same getLines() function and I don't have to write more of the same code. meaning in this funtion

```
function getLines() {
  var text = $('textarea').val();
  var lines = text.split("\n");
  var requiredLines = [];
  var runtimeDB = [];
  var incorrectInfoDB = [];
  var outerfilesDB = [];
  lines.forEach(function(line) {
    number = line.match(/\d+\.\d+$/);
    if (number != null && number[0] > 0){
      requiredLines.push(line);
      if (trim_numbers(line) == "error: there were errors found during runtime"){
          //run this query for database runtimeDB
          //push this query to be outputed 
      }
      if("warning: incorrect info 1.0" == line){
          //this query for it database array 
          //push this query to be outputed 
      }
    }

  });
  return requiredLines;
}
```

adding an array for each database group

- runtimeDB
- incorrectInfoDB
- outerfilesDB

I don't know if I explained the logic correctly
but

1. first it gets all the the values higher than 0.0
2. then it does the array push to the database groups from values higher than 0.0

also, is there a way to optimize my logic?

```js
function getLines() {
  var text = $('textarea').val();
  var lines = text.split("\n");
  var requiredLines = [];
  lines.forEach(function(line) {
    number = line.match(/\d+\.\d+$/);
    if (number != null && number[0] > 0)
      requiredLines.push(line);
  });
  return requiredLines;
}


$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $('#printlogs').html(getLines().join('<br>'));
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea style="width:100%;height:120px">
error: there were errors found during runtime 12.0
warning: incorrect info 1.0
warning: file at 'C://localhost/myfiles' not found 0.0
warning: file at 'C://localhost/css' not found 0.0
warning: file at 'C://localhost/js' not found 0.0
warning: file at 'C://localhost/assets' not found 5615612.0
</textarea>

<h4>Error Log</h4>
<printlogs id="printlogs" style="color:red"></printlogs>
<br>
<p>after these logs I want to get the arrays of each group that has their own database queries for the ones printed in printlogs</p>

<p>
  ex.
</p>
<h4>runtimeDB</h4>
<p>
  //run this query for this line
</p>
<h4>incorrectInfoDB</h4>
<p>
  //run this query for this line<br> //run this other query for other line ...
</p>
```

Comment: Do I understand that all you want is to parse the lines without the number at the end, so up to 'found', so that you can compare them to your conditions ?

Comment: yes, I want to compare the ones that have values grater than 0.0 with my own lines (that do not have a number) a predetermined list with query that line belongs to.

Comment: Do you write this log ? As in, are you in the position to make it output different content than it currently does ?

Comment: @deg yes I can make any output

Comment: @deg the previous things in the textarea are there predefined initially the only thing that changes are the numbers 0.0 or higher other than that I can change the output

Answer (score 0):

I would have used a regex and match specific keywords which could be used later for comparison.

In this specific regex I match everything that has the keyword and is ending with a number and that number is not '0.0' (this is the `(?!0\.0)` part of the regex).

The regex is executed in a loop because it matches one line per iteration.

```js
function getLines(text) {
  var lines = [];
  var re = /.*?(runtime|info|myfiles|css|assets|js).*?(?!0\.0)\d+\.?\d+/g;
  while (m = re.exec(text)) {
    lines.push(m[1]);
  };

  return lines;
}

$(function() {
    $('#printlogs').html(getLines($('textarea').val()).join('<br>'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea style="width:100%;height:120px">
error: there were errors found during runtime 12.0
warning: incorrect info 1.0
warning: file at 'C://localhost/myfiles' not found 0.0
warning: file at 'C://localhost/css' not found 0.0
warning: file at 'C://localhost/js' not found 0.0
warning: file at 'C://localhost/assets' not found 5615612.0
</textarea>

<h4>Error Log</h4>
<div id="printlogs" style="color:red"></div>
```

Later in your code

```
getLines().forEach(function(line) {
    if (line === 'info') {
        // do your logic
    }
    if (line === 'js'||line ==='css'||line==='assets') {
        // do your logic
    }
});
```

Comment: I've never seen this kind of regex. How does it work? ***?(?!0\.0)\d+\.?\d+/g;**

Comment: can I use more than one word in the parentesis **runtime|info|myfiles|css|assets|js** ?like (assets 1|runtime local| js home files) would be an example

Comment: The `.*?` matches any text which does not match the rest of the regex (this is so called ungreedy match). The next part `(?!0\.0)` is a so called "negative look ahead" which means that the rest of the text should NOT start with the pattern `0\.0` and I put it to skip rows with '0.0'. The ending part `\d+\.?\d+` matches float numbers. All combined mean match all text that is ending with a float except '0.0'

Answer (score 0):

```
var thestr = "warning: file at 'C://localhost/assets' not found 5615612.0";
var voila = thestr.substr(thestr.indexOf("found") + 5);   //+ 6 to remove the leading space
console.log(thestr);
console.log(thestr.indexOf("found"));
console.log(voila);
```

Here is how you split the string at "found", but it smells.

I would codify the errors and add the code in a well recognizable spot in the log line - that is of course if you are the one to choose what goes in the log. I.e.

```
0001::warning: whatever text
```

Then you can just parse the first characters of each line, or split the line on "::", and know you encountered a "0001" error. And apply a similar easily parsable approach to the value now at the end of the line.